# Build with maven in docker throw {}->unix://localhost:80: No such file or director

Tags: windows, maven, docker, jhipster, windows-container

I have an issue since few days I didn't have before. When I launch `./mvnw -Pprod package -DskipTests=true docker:build` in my container I have this log

```
[INFO] Copying src/main/docker/app.yml -> /home/jhipster/app/target/docker/app.yml
[INFO] Copying src/main/docker/Dockerfile -> /home/jhipster/app/target/docker/Dockerfile
[INFO] Copying src/main/docker/postgresql.yml -> /home/jhipster/app/target/docker/postgresql.yml
[INFO] Copying src/main/docker/sonar.yml -> /home/jhipster/app/target/docker/sonar.yml
[INFO] Building image projectName
May 03, 2017 8:50:21 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->unix://localhost:80: No such file or directory
May 03, 2017 8:50:21 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->unix://localhost:80
May 03, 2017 8:50:21 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->unix://localhost:80: No such file or directory
May 03, 2017 8:50:21 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->unix://localhost:80
May 03, 2017 8:50:21 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->unix://localhost:80: No such file or directory
May 03, 2017 8:50:21 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->unix://localhost:80
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 06:23 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-03T20:50:21+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 63M/226M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.13:build (default-cli) on project projectName: Exception caught: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

But if I launch the build without the production flag I don't have issue `./mvnw  -DskipTests=true docker:build`

Why I can't use `docker:build` in my container ?

Thanks

Comment: I tried to update DOCKER_HOST without success, nobody had this issue ?

Comment: I was an non understanding, `docker:build` is to use outside container https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/5736

Answer (score 0):

Your docker daemon might not be running. Make sure it is running and try again